# Нужно зайти на веб камеру (регистратор), как передать логин и пароль?

Tags: python, requests, login

Хотел решить небольшую задачку - по запросу телеграм бот присылает  картинку с камеры (регистратора) который находится дома.
Картинка формируется ссылкой вида

```
http://admin:passwd@ip-cam/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/101/picture?snapShotImageType=JPEG
```

Где admin - логин, passwd - пароль от регистратора, ip-cam - IP регистратора.
Пытался зайти используя модуль requests, но передать логин и пароль не выходит.
Окно входа ниже. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить эту задачу. Регистратор Hi-Watch
Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте библиотеку Selenium, она имитирует использование браузера пользователем, там есть методы которые работают с alert в браузере. Думаю вам как раз это и нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как решил - в requests.get прописал auth=HTTPDigestAuth:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('login', 'pass'))
if response.status_code==200:
  with open(filename,'wb') as imgfile:
   imgfile.write(response.content)
```